# Structs without ifdefs in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, struct

There are some C projects with structs full of ifdefs (for ex. WolfSSL https://github.com/wolfSSL/wolfssl/blob/bb70fee1ecff8945af8179f48e90d78ea7007c66/wolfssl/internal.h#L2792)

```
struct {
int filed_1;
int field_2;
#ifdef SETTING_A
    int filed_b;
#endif
#ifdef SETTING_B
    int field_b;
#endif
}
```

The reason is to reduce struct size for unused options.
There are a lot of ifdefs! Everywhere!

Is there a C++ way to get rid of those ifdefs, retaining the ability for compiler to optimize out unused fields?
Maybe with templates, usings or CRTP inheritance?

Comment: You're looking at a C project. Not much is possible in C with regard to this. In C++ you can just use (multiple) inheritance.

Comment: С++ inheritance uses virtual pointer table and thus impacts performance. Also this approach requires to have 4 different classes for 2 settings. What if I have 10 settings?

Comment: inheritance doesn't imply a vtable

Comment: Even _if_ you were able to do this, all users of the code still need to do compile-time checks whether field_a and field_b exist.

Comment: @XeenychXeenych A struct with no virtual members has no virtual overhead

Comment: Ok, got it. How about dealing with 10 settings?

Comment: Not, the reason is not only that.  The main reason is to avoid name pollution in the binary, with many unused fields that can make difficult to select a proper name to a new field in case you need to add.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[You can do it in C++20](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1cebb8977a66aaa) with [`[[no_unique_address]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address) and some chicanary. This isn't guaranteed result in smaller types however, so I still suggest you use the `#define`s

```
template<typename>
struct Empty {};

template<typename T, bool enable, typename uniquer>
using MaybeEmpty = std::conditional_t<enable, T, Empty<uniquer>>;

struct foo {
    int filed_1;
    int field_2;
    [[no_unique_address]] MaybeEmpty<int, settingA, struct filed_b_uniquer> filed_b;
    [[no_unique_address]] MaybeEmpty<int, settingB, struct field_b_uniquer> field_b;
};
```

Prior to C++20, that would have to be done with base classes

```
struct with_filed_b {
    int filed_b;
};

struct with_field_b {
    int field_b;
};

struct foo : MaybeEmpty<with_filed_b, settingA, struct filed_b_uniquer>, MaybeEmpty<with_field_b , settingB, struct field_b_uniquer>  {
    int filed_1;
    int field_2;        
};
```

Comment: Looks good. How about older C++?

Comment: @XeenychXeenych before then the only way of having empty objects take up no space was them being base subobjects

Comment: Could you provide an example, please?